# Dimension of a tensor algebra quotient

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

For example, for arbitrary $V$ we can find a dimension of $ \bigwedge V = T(V) / (u \otimes u)$ by writing basis explicitly -- the dimension of $\bigwedge V$ is $2^{\dim{V}}$.

Let's consider a tensor algebra $T(V)$ of a vector space $V =  \mathbb{ C}^{2}$ with a standard basis $(e_{1}, e_{2})$.

More generally: how to find the dimension tensor algebra quotient by arbitrary ideal? For instance, let $I = (e_{1} \otimes e_{1}, e_{2} \otimes e_{2}, e_{1} \otimes e_{2} + e_{2} \otimes e_{1} - 1)$ be an two-sided ideal, $A = T(V) / (I)$. How to find the dimension of $A$? The quotient may be described as a free algebra, generated by $e_{1}, e_{2}$ with the given relations: $e_{1} \otimes e_{1} = 0,  e_{2} \otimes e_{2}=0, e_{1} \otimes e_{2} + e_{2} \otimes e_{1}=1$ but  deriving the desired result from the given data seems to be tricky enough. Are there any hints that might help?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You may note that $A$ has a filtration (induced by the natural grading on $T(V)$) and the relations imply that $A=A^{\leq 2}$. By the way, your relations are incorrect for $\bigwedge V$: you want to mod out by $u\otimes v+v\otimes u$. In $A$, the relations can be expressed economically by $e_i\otimes e_j+e_j\otimes e_i=1-\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: @DavidHill His relations for $\bigwedge V$ are fine actually, and the way he wrote it works better for $V$ over a field of characteristic 2.  In characteristic not 2 the ideal you are describing is the same as the one generated by $u\otimes u$ for $u\in V$. To see why, consider the element $(u+v)\otimes (u+v)$ of his ideal.

Comment: @ebrahim You're right. I was just being stupid.

Comment: To do this in general, you need something like Bergman's Diamond Lemma (google for it), which is a noncommutative analogue of groebner bases.

Answer (score 1):

There are better answers than mine since I have little experience with this. I'll just share how I approach these dimension questions.

I think that finding a basis really is the way to go. The tensor algebra is graded by $T(V)=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}} T_n(V)$, where $T_n(V)=V^{\otimes n}$ has a basis given by $n$-fold tensors of basis elements $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ of $V$. I usually try to get better and better upper bounds on the dimension by considering how the relations allow me to rewrite these $n$-fold tensors of basis elements. Let me try on your example.

In your example, the third relation suggests that any $n$-fold tensor of $e_1$ and $e_2$ could be reordered so that all $e_1$'s appear before all $e_2$'s, at the expense of adding some lower grade terms. That is,
$$
e_{i_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes e_{i_n} = e_1\otimes \cdots \otimes e_1 \otimes e_2\otimes \cdots \otimes e_2+[\text{lower terms}]
$$
But then the first two relations kill off any pair of adjacent $e_1$'s or $e_2$'s. Thus the first term above is zero whenever $n>2$. So any $n$-fold tensor of $e_1,e_2$ could be written as a sum of lower grade terms if $n>2$. Thus the subspace $T_2(V)/I$ of $T(V)/I$ is in fact everything. Better yet, $1,e_1,e_2,e_1\otimes e_2$ span the algebra (i.e. you don't need $e_2\otimes e_1$).

It remains to find a basis. Are $1,e_1,e_2,e_1\otimes e_2$ linearly independent in $A$? [EDIT: The comments mention some decent ways to approach this.]

Comment: Mariano, in his comment to the OP, suggested the appropriate keyword to search for: Bergman's diamond lemma. See this article by Bergman ( http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870878900105 ), and his errata ( https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/papers/updates/diamond.html ); the thesis by Hellström ( http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:145049/FULLTEXT01.pdf ), that by Ge ( http://etd.uwaterloo.ca/etd/w2ge2006.pdf ), and various other places concerned with noncommutative Gröbner bases. In many specific cases, there are proofs of linear independence that ...

Comment: ... do not use the diamond lemma, but as a general method the diamond lemma (in its various versions) is more or less the main tool.